# Self made neural network failing detecting hand written digits, however works fine for other benchmark datasets

Tags: python, neural-network, mnist, softmax

I have created a neural network from scratch. It is working fine for some benchmark datasets such as Iris, Make Moons, etc. but fails with the MNIST dataset. I have reviewed the code several times and failed to locate any mistakes.

I have tried different combinations of activation functions along with very high learning rates- 500, 1000, etc. I have also tried different architectures; having several layers with many neurons. None of them worked.

Please note that calculate_delta_final and the derivative of softmax function might seem a bit odd that's because I tried to facilitate both mean squared error and categorical cross-entropy.
As dZL for softmax is (Y_hat - Y) directly, I return 1 for softmax derivative although derivative of softmax is not 1.

I unfortunately am sharing the whole notebook as I have no idea what is causing the issue. Link to the notebook is here:

https://github.com/mcagriardic/Andrew-NG-Coursera/blob/master/ex4/NeuralNetwork_class.ipynb

Comment: Are you checking if you are processing the images correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. The problem was origination from the way the weights were initialised. Thanks for taking your time and checking my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The issue was originating because of the way I was initializing my weights:

The previous code for initialise_weights() function was:

```
    def initialise_weights(self, layer=None):
    self.W = np.empty_like(range(self.layers), dtype=object)
    self.B = np.empty_like(range(self.layers), dtype=object)
    self.W[0] = None
    self.B[0] = None
    for layer, (y, x) in zip(range(1, self.layers), self.weight_set_dimensions):
        np.random.seed(self.seed)
        self.W[layer] = np.random.rand(y, x)
        self.B[layer] = np.random.rand(y, 1)
```

After dividing the initialised weights with  np.sqrt(self.dimensions[layer - 1]) term, the problem was solved.

```
    def initialise_weights(self, layer=None):
    self.W = np.empty_like(range(self.layers), dtype=object)
    self.B = np.empty_like(range(self.layers), dtype=object)
    self.W[0] = None
    self.B[0] = None
    for layer, (y, x) in zip(range(1, self.layers), self.weight_set_dimensions):
        np.random.seed(self.seed)
        self.W[layer] = np.random.rand(y, x) / np.sqrt(self.dimensions[layer - 1])
        self.B[layer] = np.random.rand(y, 1)
```